# SSH - connection is closed immediately after trying to login

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

So getting an issue with trying to login to a server via SSH.

```
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 193.68.68.50 ([193.68.68.50]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem full
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env __CFBundleIdentifier
debug3: Ignored env COMMAND_MODE
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR
debug3: Ignored env XPC_SERVICE_NAME
debug3: Ignored env XPC_FLAGS
debug3: Ignored env ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env HOMEBREW_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env HOMEBREW_CELLAR
debug3: Ignored env HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY
debug3: Ignored env MANPATH
debug3: Ignored env INFOPATH
debug3: Ignored env rvm_prefix
debug3: Ignored env rvm_path
debug3: Ignored env rvm_bin_path
debug3: Ignored env rvm_version
debug3: Ignored env GEM_HOME
debug3: Ignored env GEM_PATH
debug3: Ignored env MY_RUBY_HOME
debug3: Ignored env IRBRC
debug3: Ignored env RUBY_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: chan_shutdown_read: channel 0: (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
Last login: Sat Apr  2 05:52:40 2022 from 192.168.133.1
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: chan_shutdown_write: channel 0: (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Connection to 193.68.68.50 closed.
Transferred: sent 3200, received 2648 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 143439.9, received 118696.5
debug1: Exit status 254
```

Looking forward to your help, on how to fix this issue. This happens while login in from a basic user.

If i'm trying to do that via root user i get

```
Unable to get valid context for root
```

Comment: You'll get the answer to your question in the `auth.log` on the server. Is there any way you can get to that, or have someone get it for you?

Comment: @roaima Currently there is no, need to get directly to the place where the server is located.

Comment: You're getting the login headline `Last login: Sat Apr  2 05:52:40 2022 from 192.168.133.1` so the likelihood is that there's something in your startup files (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, etc.) forcing a logout. You might be able to rename them through `sftp` _if but only if_ it's been configured to use the internal server.

Comment: I wonder if you can bypass the problem by executing a remote command for example "ssh remote-host /bin/sh"

Comment: @PhilipCouling Nope, no luck